# Get WebGLDeferredRenderer working with SSAO

Tags: three.js

Here are comparisons, to show that I do indeed have SSAO set-up correctly.

**WebGLRenderer with EffectsComposer + SSAO pass**
[image: WebGLRenderer with EffectsComposer + SSAO pass]

**WebGLDeferredRenderer with SSAO pass**
[image: WebGLDeferredRenderer with SSAO pass]

I'm trying to mix WebGLDeferredRenderer with the SSAO composer effect like so:

```
renderer = new THREE.WebGLDeferredRenderer({
  antialias: true,
  tonemapping: THREE.FilmicOperator,
  brightness: 2.5,
  scale: 1.0,
  width: renderWidth,
  height: renderHeight
});

var depthShader = THREE.ShaderLib[ "depthRGBA" ];
var depthUniforms = THREE.UniformsUtils.clone( depthShader.uniforms );

depthMaterial = new THREE.ShaderMaterial( { fragmentShader: depthShader.fragmentShader, vertexShader: depthShader.vertexShader, uniforms: depthUniforms } );
depthMaterial.blending = THREE.NoBlending;

composer = new THREE.EffectComposer( renderer );
composer.setSize( window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight );

depthTarget = new THREE.WebGLRenderTarget( window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight, {
  minFilter: THREE.NearestFilter,
  magFilter: THREE.NearestFilter,
  format: THREE.RGBAFormat,
  antialias: true
});

var ssao = new THREE.ShaderPass( THREE.SSAOShader );
ssao.uniforms[ 'tDepth' ].value = depthTarget;
ssao.uniforms[ 'size' ].value.set( window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight );
ssao.uniforms[ 'cameraNear' ].value = camera.near;
ssao.uniforms[ 'cameraFar' ].value = camera.far * 0.8;
ssao.uniforms[ 'aoClamp' ].value = 0.3;
ssao.uniforms[ 'lumInfluence' ].value = 0.1;

renderer.addEffect( ssao );

scene.overrideMaterial = depthMaterial;
renderer.render( scene, camera, depthTarget );
scene.overrideMaterial = null;

renderer.render( scene, camera );
```

The results are.. well.. nothing.

What am I doing wrong? How would I go about enabling SSAO within a deferred renderer?

Answer (score 3):

Not sure why this works but try replacing:

`renderer.render( scene, camera, depthTarget );`

With:

`renderer.renderer.render( scene, camera, depthTarget );`

Comment: This is it! Thank's @aki. The reason why it was broken for me was because the WebGLDeferredRenderer is just a shell that holds onto a reference to the actual WebGLRenderer. In which case, it should be called to render via renderer.renderer.render() ...... yikes!

In addition to this, one must set forceClear via renderer.renderer.render( scene, camera, depthTarget, true ); for this mix to work.